# Como agregar una condicion en este codigo

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguiente funcion en javacritps, pero deseo poder agregar una condiccion si el Pedido esta con si, el checkbox quede `disable`

```
  function MuestraDatos(Valor) {
        data = JSON.parse(Valor);
        var indice = 0;
        //alert("entra a mostrar");
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            /* Vamos agregando a nuestra tabla las filas necesarias */
            indice = indice + 1;
            $("#TablaCargaOP").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + value.OP + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Item + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.CodPza + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Desc + "</td>" +
                "<td data-name='Cantidad' class='Cantidad' data-type='text'>" + value.CantPzas + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.QueNivel + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Pedido + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + if (value.Pedido == 'SI') {
                  " <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' disable class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>"
                } else {
                  " <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>"
                }  +
                "</tr>");
        });
        $('#TablaCargaOP').ddTableFilter();
}
```

Obtengo el siguiente error

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'
```

Comment: si si hubieses colocado todo el if/else en parentesis funcionaria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El problema es que metes código en la concatenación (`+`) de
>   *strings*, y no sabe que hacer dado que no es ningún tipo de dato especifico.

Prueba con lo siguiente, que es definir fuera con el `if` que `td` corresponde asignar el *string* a una variable y luego concatenarla.

```
function MuestraDatos(Valor) {
        data = JSON.parse(Valor);
        var indice = 0;
        //alert("entra a mostrar");
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            /* Vamos agregando a nuestra tabla las filas necesarias */
            indice = indice + 1;

            var tdToAdd;
            if (value.Pedido == 'SI') {
                 tdToAdd = "<td> <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' disable class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>"
                } 
                else {
                  tdToAdd = "<td> <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>"
            }

            $("#TablaCargaOP").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + value.OP + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Item + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.CodPza + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Desc + "</td>" +
                "<td data-name='Cantidad' class='Cantidad' data-type='text'>" + value.CantPzas + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.QueNivel + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.Pedido + "</td>" +
                tdToAdd +
                "</tr>");
        });
        $('#TablaCargaOP').ddTableFilter();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

tenes un error de sintaxis en la línea

```
"<td>" + if (value.Pedido == 'SI') ...
```

Para solucionarlo tenes dos alternativas, una es terminar de concatenar el `string`, luego evaluar la condición, y ahí sumarle (o no) lo que falta

Caso contrario, la otra opción, sería utilizar un [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) (que asumo que es lo que más se acerca a lo que queres hacer)

Sería algo así.

```
"<td>" + (value.Pedido == 'SI' ? "HtmlSiSeCumple" : "HtmlSiNoSeCumple") ...
```

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema esta dado porque en una operación de suma de cadenas (concatenación) no puedes incluir una sentencia if, ya que el solo espera un operando que puede ser otra cadena, un numero, una función o una variable. Para solucionar esto si te fijas bien la unica diferencia entre el texto que incluyes cuando la condición se cumple y cuando no se cumple es que en el primer caso al checkbox le agregas o le quitas el atributo disabled, por tanto puedes hacer lo siguiente, asi evitas repetir código innecesario.

```
var pedido = "<div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' "+((value.Pedido == 'SI') ? 'disabled ' : '')+ "class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>" :
$("#TablaCargaOP").append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + value.OP + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value.Item + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value.CodPza + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value.Desc + "</td>" +
    "<td data-name='Cantidad' class='Cantidad' data-type='text'>" + value.CantPzas + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value.QueNivel + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value.Pedido + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + pedido +
    "</tr>");
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás intentando concatenar un `if` con cadenas de texto. Tu codigo deberia quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
function MuestraDatos(Valor) {
  data = JSON.parse(Valor);
  var indice = 0;
  //alert("entra a mostrar");
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      /* Vamos agregando a nuestra tabla las filas necesarias */
      indice = indice + 1;
      $("#TablaCargaOP").append("<tr>" +
          "<td>" + value.OP + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + value.Item + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + value.CodPza + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + value.Desc + "</td>" +
          "<td data-name='Cantidad' class='Cantidad' data-type='text'>" + value.CantPzas + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + value.QueNivel + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + value.Pedido + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + " <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' " + (value.Pedido == 'SI' ? 'disable' : '') + " class='form-check-input' id='Escoge"+indice+"' name='Escoge'/>" + " <label class='form-check-label' for='Escoge"+indice+"'></label></div></td>" +
          "</tr>");
  });
  $('#TablaCargaOP').ddTableFilter();
}
```

La expresión `(value.Pedido == 'SI' ? 'disable' : '')` hace referencia a un [operador ternario](https://picandocodigo.net/2009/operador-ternario-operador-condicional/), el cual sirve para evaluar condicionales en una sola linea (muy útiles en casos como el tuyo).

Saludos!